# Variable product add to cart in Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have two variations for a product which is of weight 0.5 kg and 1 kg.
I have defaultly selected 1 kg and when clicking add to cart button then 1 kg product is adding to the cart but i need when i click another button swatch buy i want to add 0.5 kg product defaultly to the cart and redirect it to cart page. Can u help me to solve this as i am new to woocommerce.
I am using this to add the product with id ang slug name. its just redirecting to cart page but not adding to cart

```
<a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/index.php/cart?add-to-cart=<?php echo $product->id ?>&variation_id=2775&attribute_pa_weight-gms-per-meter=0-5" class="single_add_to_cart_button button">swatch buy</a>
```

Comment: variable id's for different products are different then how i can solve this problem

Comment: get help from [https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-add-cart-urls-ultimate-guide/] here & also check for **premalink** settings.